# The critical components that define an Adv tourer from other motorcycles

Tags: engine, motorcycle, ktm

Mainly want to understand the running of an adv tourer. 
1) what is the basic difference between the showa suspensions,WP suspensions and an upside down fork? 
Advantages & disadvantages of the three.

2)Why dont adv tourers come with alloys but spoke wheels? Aren't alloys much advanced and stronger? I have read that spoke wheels handle the dirt better, so if i have spoke wheels does that mean iam compromising the same for on-road (highway) purpose?

3)How do the suspension adjustments work (adjustable upside down fork)? How do i know what kind of adjustment i would need for a given situation? What is the kind of maintenance do these suspensions demand?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good fit for the site ... it is more about opinion and purchasing than about MVM&R.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more about opinion and purchasing than about MVM&R.

Comment: As it stands, this question is very broad. It also solicits opinion. If you could narrow down the reliability to certain features of motorcycles, and how durable particular components may be, as well as known failure points, etc, you might have better luck at getting an answerable question. Try to concentrate on points that can be factually answered, possibly with research.)

Comment: My first on the site. As i see it doesnt comply with your r&r. Point taken,  ill work on my question.

Comment: @Seeker   Here's an upside down fork QA that you may like.   :-)      http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/25832/what-are-the-advantages-of-upside-down-forks/25916#25916